# FileVault personal recovery key

Tags: icloud, apple-id, filevault, recovery

How is PRK generated/derived and what is being sent to Apple's servers if I choose "use this iCloud account to unlock and reset your password..." during FileVault setup? I wasn't able to find this in FileVault technical whitepaper. Is it just yet another DEK (Data Encryption Key)?

Comment: What does DEK stand for? Data or Derived Encryption Key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The personal recovery key is read from /dev/random and base32 encoded afterwards:

> ... When activating FileVault 2, the
>   System Preferences application displays a randomly generated
>   120 bit password, encoded with base32, to the end
>   user and advises them to securely store the password for
>   recovery (see figure 2). The recovery password is read
>   from /dev/random (through libcsfde and SecCreateRecoveryPassword()
>   in Security.framework).

Source: [Infiltrate the Vault: Security Analysis and Decryption of Lion Full Disk Encryption, page 9](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/374.pdf)

Comment: What relations does it have with other keys? Is it just a randomly generated DEK?

Comment: It depends how you expand DEK! This can be seen in page 8, figure 8. It's one of several possible "keys" for key derivation. It's **no** DataEK but a DerivedEK.

Comment: That's the only thing sent to Apple's servers, right?

Comment: @assp1r1n3 I never checked the content of the IP-packets but I assume it's the only thing sent to iCloud but encrypted again (probably with some temp key).